# Execution exception

Tags: exception, playframework

I am following the Play framework tutorial, and to the point opening the tasks page but it constantly returns the following error which I can't seem to fix:

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: views/html/index$$anonfun$apply$1, method: apply signature: (Lmodels/Task;)Lplay/api/templates/Html;) Expecting to find integer on stack]
```

Can anyone point me to where to look for an error? I've tried JDK 6 & 7 32 & 64 bit versions all to no avail.

Here is my Index.scala.html:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {

<h1>@tasks.size() task(s)</h1>

<ul>
    @for(task <- tasks) {
    <li>
        @task.label

        @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        }
    </li>
    }
</ul>

<h2>Add a new task</h2>

@form(routes.Application.newTask()) {

    @inputText(taskForm("label"))

    <input type="submit" value="Create">

}

}
```

Comment: Could you please add your `index.scala.html` template? From the error message, that seems to be where the error is located.

Comment: I have changed the type of the id field of Class Task to Integer and it works. This fixes the problem, but I don't understand why a Long Int is throwing an exception - any ideas?